# In this case from Nygard's "Release it!" why do deadlocks happen?

Tags: threadpool, deadlock, connection-pooling, database-performance, database-deadlocks

I'm reading over and over this paragraph from Michael Nygard's book "Release it!" and I still don't understand why exactly deadlocks can happen:

> Imagine 100,000 transactions all trying to update the same row of the
>   same table in the same database. Somebody is bound to get deadlocked.
>   Once a single transaction with a lock on the user’s profile got hung
>   (because of the need for a connection from a different resource pool),
>   all the other database transactions on that row got blocked. Pretty
>   soon, every single request-handling thread got used up with these
>   bogus logins. As soon as that happens, the site is down.

When he says "because of the need for a connection from a different resource pool", is this inside the DB engine? What is this other resource pool and why would a connection from this other resource pool be needed?

Then, "every single request-handling thread" refers already not to DB threads, but to application threads, right? And they hung because they're waiting for the DB transactions (that are already hung) to finish?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [cs.se]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in that applications interface with a LOT of different systems, any of which can run in parallel, have internal or external locks, and depend on yet more systems.

A simple example of a deadlock is basically when two processes need to acquire exactly the same two locks at the same time to proceed, but can't agree to who will go first and in which order (which is usually what the locks are for in the first place, so it's a chicken-and-the-egg problem, not exactly trivial). So processes A and B need to acquire two locks, #1 and #2, to do their thing and proceed. But while A is locking #1, B is locking #2, and then A tries to lock #2 and B tries to lock #1 - *that's* a deadlock. Someone's got to give in for any work to be done.

In real life, let's say you're running multiple instances of your web application, to be able to serve multiple incoming client requests (e.g. web browsers) at the same time. It doesn't matter if those are threads, processes or coroutines. Instances of your application can hang if they require locks on two database rows. Or they can hang because in addition to a database lock, they also need a lock on a file in the file system. Or they can hang because they need a lock on a file in the file system and they are using a third party remote REST API which also has locks of its own. Or because of infinite other reasons including all of the above simultaneously.